# Passing javascript object as an argument to a function - typescript equivalent

Tags: javascript, function, parameter-passing

I'm trying to better understand the code in this example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/r5n96yvwnm

So there is this function (lines 9-11):

```
function MyCell({ value, columnProps: { rest: { someFunc } } }) {
  return <a href="#" onClick={someFunc}>{value}</a>
}
```

What construct is it, and is it possible to translate it easily into Typescript? I mean, I could go ahead and create a typescript interface with all needed props but I was wondering, if there is any shorter way of doing so. I have never seen a construct like this, so any links with more explanation appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You may be confused about the [destructing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) occurring here.

Comment: if you don't want to make a separate interfact try `function MyCell({ value, columnProps: { rest: { someFunc } } }:{ value: number, columnProps: { rest: { someFunc: () => void } } })`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function MyCell({ value, columnProps: { rest: { someFunc } } }) {
```

This part is using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to pick the properties off of an object. It's the same as:

```
function MyCell(props) {
  const value = props.value;
  const columnProps = props.columnProps;
  const rest = columnProps.rest;
  const someFunc = rest.someFunc;
```

Doing this with typescript would look something like this (i'm guessing at some of the types in the interface):

```
interface MyCellProps {
  value: number;
  columnProps: {
    rest: {
      someFunc: () => void;
    }
  }
}

function MyCell: React.FC<MyCellProps>({ value, columnProps: { rest: { someFunc } } }) {
   return <a href="#" onClick={someFunc}>{value}</a>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the params are confusing you. `MyCell` is a function that takes a single parameter. That parameter is expected to be an object with properties `value` and `columnProps`. `columnProps` is also expected to be an object, with the property `rest`. `rest` is likewise expected to be an obj with prop `someFunc`.

This is called `object destructuring`, and in the specific case of using it in parameters, it's called `unpacking` ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter)).